# c - updating strings defined as char pointer variables

Tags: c, string

The head first C book mentions correctly that:

> A variable that points to a string literal can’t be used to change the
> contents of the string

for example, defining `char *cards = "jqk";` and then trying to change `cards` by doing something like `card[1] = 'q';` wont work.

This is quite obvious because here `*cards` is merely pointing to a the memory address of the start of string literal "jqk" which is stored in the `read-only` CONSTANTS section of memory, which by definition can't be written to.

But when we do something like `char cards[] = "jqk";` we are actually--while initializing the character array cards--copying the string literal "jqk" from the `CONSTANT` memory block to the `STACK` (which is writable) and cards is now a pointer to the first element of this array...so this string can be manipulated (changed)... I hope my understanding is correct so far.

A few chapters ahead, a program listing does something like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char *delivery = "";
        ...

        while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != EOF)
                switch (ch) {
                        case 'd':
                                delivery = optarg;
                                break;
                        ...            
}
```

So this program is defining `delivery` as a pointer to the string literal `""`, and then goes on to update `delivery` to the value of `optarg` for option `d`. So how is this updation working?

**EDIT**
does it work because in this case we are not trying to mutate the string literal `""`, but updating the pointer variable to point from the previous string literal `""` to now the string literal copy in stack which is pointed to by `optarg`...

As in, `from *delivery -> &""` to `*delivery -> memory_address_of_optarg`

Comment: @user3121023, just saw this. I had an aha moment of sorts while you  were answering (edited post). Was my understanding correct?

Comment: You've got it, except that the string which `optarg` points to is probably not on the stack, but rather in dynamically allocated memory.  And it's probably not a copy of any string literal, but of some part of one of the strings which the `argv` vector points to.